# Get child list of parent process in C

Tags: c, linux, process

I have a PID of process that may contain childs. How can I get the PID of all child processes? I make my own PTY handler, so when user run a shell in this handler he may run anymore programs ( directly from shell ), every ran program becomes a child of shell. So, when I press Ctrl+C I need to send signal to the most new process, so need to know PID of that last one.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is the real use case? Please edit your question to improve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep *explicitly* all the pids (result of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)...) of your child processes (and remove a pid once you waited it successfully with [wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) etc...)

<sup>It is up to you to choose the data structures to keep these pids.</sup>

Any other approach (e.g. using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)... which is what `ps` and `pstree` are doing.) is not very portable and inefficient.

So the basic rule is that every time you call `fork` you should explicitly keep its result (and test for the 3 cases: 0 if in child process, >0 if in parent process, <0 on error) and use that at `wait` time.

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/); it has many pages relevant to that subject.

You might also be interested by [process groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) and sessions. See [setpgrp(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgrp.2.html), [setsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html), [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) etc. Notice that with a negative or zero pid [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) can send a signal to a process group, and that you could also use [killpg(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html) for that purpose.

Comment: fork() makes new process, right? But in my case I already have childs, i just need to analyze them

Comment: It is *your program* which has childs. So you wrote the program, and you wrote (perhaps indirectly) the invocation of `fork` which is the only way your program could have children processes. You need to improve your program to manage all the pids of your child processes.

Comment: Well, my program makes a child, this child have to be a shell ( bash, sh etc). From bash user can run anymore processes. So my problem to get PID of process that `bash` will call.

Comment: These are not the children of your process. At most the grand-children.

Comment: `killpg` exactly I was looking for

Comment: Faced this problem... It is not easy to get this idea working correctly, because you should keep process list and remove dead childs from it. But you can't use bunch of system functions inside SIGCHLD handler (man 7 signal for list of safe sys functions) and you can't allocate/free memory inside it (free in chld signal handler can lead to deadlock when signal rised inside fork()). So you should add/delete childs to list inside main process and should pass dead child pid there and care about lost pids......